# Setting data on Android retained Fragment before onCreate() has been called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that creates a retained Fragment in order to persist a long running network operation in the event that the Activity goes through any configuration changes during the long running operation. So basically I'm trying to use the retained Fragment like a Singleton that lives until Activity's onDestroy() is called.

My goal is to have Activity's onCreate() trigger the long running network operation because I only want it to run when the activity is created not every time it starts again (otherwise I'd put it in onStart()).

To do this I first create a retained fragment in Activity's onCreate, then use FragmentManager to add the retained fragment then I kick off the network call in Activity's onCreate method and pass the networking object to the retained Fragment to hold onto.

This works, however I'm concerned because if I log what's going on I can see that the Activity first sets data on the retained Fragment and then the retained Fragment's onCreate() method is called. This looks wrong and seems out of order, however it works.

Is it bad practice to utilize the retained Fragment instance before the fragment has run its onCreate() method?

**EDIT**
After reading the responses and thinking a bit more about this, I'm realizing that initiating the network call from Activity onCreate() although convenient, is risky to do. As noted in the responses there's a chance that the long running operation returns very quickly and attempts to manipulate the Activity's view which may not have been initialized yet. So for my specific case I am resorting to initiating the long running operation from Activity's onStart() method and then using the retainedFragment to cache the response. This way even if onStart() is called multiple times and attempts to kick off the long running operation again, the result from the first attempt will be cached and can be returned.

Comment: you can separate your long network operation in a separate service, and just call the service from the onCreate

Comment: Services are a solution but they seem heavy-handed for what I'm trying to accomplish also with a Service you need to either implement some sort of event bus to communicate results back or bind to the service so you can communicate directly with it which I'm trying to avoid. The problem I'm trying to solve is starting an asynchronous operation that finishes relatively quickly but allows enough time for a configuration change (like rotating the device).

Comment: network operations should be run on a thread other than the UI thread so either you have to use AsyncTask or go with Services. Because onCreate will call each time you rotate your device, a new instance will run. But with services, it will run in the background and you can communicate with the service simply through sharepreferences and a sharepreferencelistener

Comment: Network operations must be performed off the UI thread but AsyncTask or Services are not the only way to do that. In fact, Services run on the UI thread unless you spin up a worker thread within them.

Comment: What I meant about the service, is IntentService not the Service class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will admit that's unusual, but I can't think of a reason off the top of my head why it would be bad.  The advantage of a retained Fragment is the reference to the Fragment is not destroyed so the references it holds on to are also retained. `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are called once throughout the lifetime of the Fragment (when the Fragment is added and removed respectively).

The danger might be that the asynchronous operation finishes before `onCreate()` is called. Likewise, the operation could finish after `onDestroy()` is called and when you expected the Fragment to be running. There are some methods like `Fragment#setArguments()` that can *not* be called during some parts of the `Fragment's` lifecycle.  If you were to call these methods when you expected the `Fragment` to be running, then you will get an Exception thrown. So you end up having to put in a bunch of checks like `if(isAttached()) { /* do this */ }`.  Putting the operation in `onCreate()` will ensure that it at least *started* before the operation finished.

But if you are not actually relying on any of the `Fragment's` functionality, then it should be fine. The lifecycles are only meant to tell you what's going on with it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not relying on Activity/Fragment views being available while Fragment's `onCreate`, you will be fine:

> Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point.

(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

Still, you need to secure possible edge case that long-running operation may be finished before Activity and Fragment are fully created (if you depend on their views, this might be an issue).
Therefore, think about what you will do when long-running operation has finished and the results need to be presented somewhere.